# Visual Studio 2013 not displaying any code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

Visual Studio 2013 isn't displaying my Code anymore. It happened from one day to another.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. I hope someone can help me. Already tried to change the color of the theme, but it didn't fix it.

[Picture of my Visual Studio not displaying any code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9frRX.png)

Comment: Try to reset your interface. A reinstall may be required.

Comment: Close your vs and open it again.

Comment: Any extensions or addins installed?

Comment: @FrankerZ it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: @MojtabaNava did it several times, no effect on my problem,
Extensions: ReSharper Ultimate, NuGet Package Manager, MS Web Developer Tools
Add-Ins: None

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Resharper and restart your windows.
Your extensions need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it by myself. It was ReSharper indeed @Mojtaba Nava, but I just updated it and restarted my PC. and now the code is being displayed. Thanks for the hint!

Solved.